# Activator Active Stocks starter application fails to run with java.io.IOException?

Tags: linux, scala, playframework, typesafe

I got the latest version of typesafe activator in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I also have the latest version of Scala/SBT etc etc.

When I start the Active Stocks application I get the following error `java.io.IOException: User limit of inotify watches reached`. I have no idea what this is ...

```
bravegag@zeus:~/code/activestocks$ ./activator
[info] Loading project definition from /home/bravegag/code/activestocks/project
[info] Set current project to reactive-stocks (in build file:/home/bravegag/code/activestocks/)
[reactive-stocks] $ ~run

java.io.IOException: User limit of inotify watches reached
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.implRegister(LinuxWatchService.java:261)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.processRequests(AbstractPoller.java:260)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run(LinuxWatchService.java:326)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Nov 29, 2014 4:57:15 PM
1. Waiting for source changes... (press enter to interrupt)
```

Checking OS limits I see:

```
bravegag@zeus:~$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
128
bravegag@zeus:~$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
8192
```

Comment: Have you tried to raise that value: `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=30000`?

Comment: Yes indeed putting this into /etc/sysctl.conf solves the problem permanently ... answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

not my soloution, but its always nice to have the anwser where it belongs:

```
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=30000
```

will solve the problem imminently.

otherwise set the value in `/etc/sysctl.conf` 
by simply adding `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=30000`
(don't forget the newline)

References for what actually happens can be found here: http://www.la-samhna.de/samhain/manual/finotify.html

After that `$ activator run` worked as usual.